# Why does this R code give me 1 1 0 and not 3 0 or 1 0 or 3 1 0?

Tags: r

Why does this R code return 1 1 0? I understand why there is a zero at the end because 6 divided by 2 gives a remainder of 0. But I'm not sure how we got the 1 1. I thought that 6 divided by 2 is 3. I mean, okay, I guess Recall() means that the function will be repeated so we get 3 divided by 2 is 1. But anyway, I don't understand why there are two 1s. Could someone please explain? Thanks.

```
binary <- function(x) {
  if(x == 0)
    numeric()
  else 
    c(Recall(x %/% 2), x %% 2)
}
binary(6)
```

Comment: the return value is "growing" until the input is 0 in which case the function terminates. the final return is actually `c(numeric(), 1 %% 2, 3 %% 2, 6 %% 2)` but the proof is left to the reader

Comment: Said differently, your expectation of `3` suggests that you think that `6 %/% 2` should be included in the output. It should not: the last line `c(Recall(x %/% 2), x %% 2)` is initially `c(Recall(6 %/% 2), 0)`, which is `c(Recall(3), 0)`, and then `Recall(3)` is called ... which iterates/recurses as @rawr said. Recursion can be difficult to visualize, certainly, but none of your return values are the result of `%/%`, they are all the result of `%%` operations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can run the same function, but with some `cat` statements so the recursive function can explain what it's doing, and in what order. Note that apart from the `cat` calls, the function is exactly the same.

```r
binary <- function(x) {
  
  # Statement 1
  cat("Function was given the value", x, "\n")
  
  if(x == 0){
    
    # Statement 2
    cat(" - Value of 0 passed, therefore stopping.\n\n")
    
    numeric()
  }
  else
  {
    # Statement 3
    cat(" - inserting the remainder (", x%%2, ") to the result\n")
    
    c(Recall(x %/% 2), x %% 2)
  }
}
```

So now we can see:

```r
binary(6)
#> Function was given the value 6 
#>  - inserting the remainder ( 0 ) to the result
#> Function was given the value 3 
#>  - inserting the remainder ( 1 ) to the result
#> Function was given the value 1 
#>  - inserting the remainder ( 1 ) to the result
#> Function was given the value 0 
#>  - Value of 0 passed, therefore stopping.
#>
#>[1] 1 1 0
```